# java crashed with SIGABRT in getX11InputMethodData() , Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, java, crash

My PC is dual boot with Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and Windows 10. No errors with Windows, but when I log in to Ubuntu **I was receiving Ubuntu 18.04 has experienced an internal error**.

[image]